# How can I modify this function to get a value in div below clicked element?

Tags: jquery

Need to get and create var from href in div below clicked element.

The var will be used elsewhere.

HTML

```
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <a title="Newest" href="#picked" class="addressClick" id=
    "https://www.foo.com/mail/5423551ae4b0a1ae195446cd" name=
    "https://www.foo.com/mail/5423551ae4b0a1ae195446cd">My stuff<span class="ltgrey">by John Smith</span></a>
    <div class="ltrFolder">
      <a title="Archive" href="list_johnsmith.html"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Current Function (gets ID from .addressClick)

```
$(function(getAddress){
  $('.addressClick').click(function(){                       
    letterLink = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(letterLink);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple traverse:

```
 $('.addressClick').click(function(){                       
    var nextLink = $(this).next().find('a');
    alert( nextLink.attr('title') ); // will alert "Archive"
 });
```

`next()` will return the next sibling, `find()` will look for descendents of that sibling

Comment: Thanks! Tried the next() with no joy before I posted. Yep, find() does the trick! I can get the href now.

Comment: when in doubt look through the jQuery api. There is a Traverse section there with examples for each method